# dynamically create an array of objects bug fix

Tags: javascript

here is the array of objects I have:

```
    var sentences = [
    { id: "1-1", layer: ["A", "X", "Y"] },
    { id: "1-2", layer: ["B", "Z"] },
    { id: "1-3", layer: ["C", "P"] },
    { id: "2-1", layer: ["D"] },
    { id: "2-2", layer: ["E"] },
    { id: "2-3", layer: ["F"] },
    { id: "3-1", layer: ["G"] },
    { id: "3-2", layer: ["H"] },
    { id: "3-3", layer: ["I"] },
    ];
```

the first number in id is the slide number and the second one is for the sentence on that slide. for example id: 3-2 is slide 3 and sentence 2.

so we have 3 slides here...

Now the problem is How can I programmatically fill the slides array like this:

```
var slides = [
{ slide_id: "1", slide_layer: ["A", "X", "Y", "B", "Z", "C", "P"] },
{ slide_id: "2", slide_layer: ["D", "E", "F"] },
{ slide_id: "3", slide_layer: ["G", "H", "I"] },
]
```

Thanks to @Nenad Vracar I have this code to do this near perfect:

```js
var sentences = [
{ id: "1-1", layer: ["A", "X", "Y"] },
{ id: "1-2", layer: ["B", "Z"] },
{ id: "1-3", layer: ["C", "P"] },
{ id: "2-1", layer: ["D"] },
{ id: "2-2", layer: ["E"] },
{ id: "2-3", layer: ["F"] },
{ id: "3-1", layer: ["G"] },
{ id: "3-2", layer: ["H"] },
{ id: "3-3", layer: ["I"] },
];

//

let result = Object.values(sentences.reduce((r, {id, layer}) => {
  let [a, b] = id.split('-');
  if(!r[a]) r[a] = { slide_id: a, slide_layer: [] }
  r[a].slide_layer[b - 1] = layer[0]
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

The problem is it only adds the first elements of layer arrays and ignores the rest.

I have tried looping through this line with no success:  `r[a].slide_layer[b - 1] = layer[i]`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `layer[0]`, you can [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the entire `layer` array to `slide_layer` using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const sentences=[{id:"1-1",layer:["A","X","Y"]},{id:"1-2",layer:["B","Z"]},{id:"1-3",layer:["C","P"]},{id:"2-1",layer:["D"]},{id:"2-2",layer:["E"]},{id:"2-3",layer:["F"]},{id:"3-1",layer:["G"]},{id:"3-2",layer:["H"]},{id:"3-3",layer:["I"]},];

const result = Object.values(sentences.reduce((r, {id, layer}) => {
  let [a, b] = id.split('-');
  if(!r[a]) r[a] = { slide_id: a, slide_layer: [] }
  r[a].slide_layer.push(...layer)
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a map and render the wanted objects later.

```js
var sentences = [{ id: "1-1", layer: ["A", "X", "Y"] }, { id: "1-2", layer: ["B", "Z"] }, { id: "1-3", layer: ["C", "P"] }, { id: "2-1", layer: ["D"] }, { id: "2-2", layer: ["E"] }, { id: "2-3", layer: ["F"] }, { id: "3-1", layer: ["G"] }, { id: "3-2", layer: ["H"] }, { id: "3-3", layer: ["I"] }],
    result = Array.from(
        sentences.reduce((m, { id, layer }) => {
            var key = id.split('-')[0];
            return m.set(key, [...(m.get(key) || []), ...layer])
        }, new Map),
        ([slide_id, slide_layer])  => ({ slide_id, slide_layer })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```